# angularjs + underscorejs promise

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js, promise

I've a table, featured with ng-table.
When I remove some element of this table I would like to refresh list of data to update my table.

I write into response of service delete this code

```
$q.all(_.reject($scope.tableParams.data, function(item){
  item._id == pid;
})).then(
  $scope.tableParams.reload()
);
```

I need to follow this path because `_.reject` is async and I used a synchronous way I will obtain a  `$scope.tableParams.reload()` before `_.reject`is complete

```
_.reject($scope.tableParams.data, function(item){
      item._id == pid;
});

$scope.tableParams.reload();
```

But the first code can't satisfy my strategy. There is any way?

**EDITED**

This is a part of my code. In this way I fill my table

```
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,
        count: 10
    }, {
        getData: function ($defer, params) {
            var queryParams = params.sorting();
            var page = params.page();
            var size = params.count();

            function initFilters(filters, queryParams){
                $scope.search = {};

                if("companyProfile" in queryParams && !("companyProfile" in filters)){
                    filters.companyProfile = ''
                    filters.companyProfile=$location.$$search["companyProfile"];
                    $scope.search.companyProfile = {};
                    $scope.search.companyProfile = filters["companyProfile"]; 

                }

                return filters;
            }

            var filters = angular.equals({}, params.filter()) ? initFilters(params.filter(), $location.$$search) : params.filter();

            partners.filter({filter: filters.companyProfile, page: page, per_page: size, start: filters.start, end: filters.end, sorting:params.sorting()}).$promise.then(
                function(response){
                    var result = response.hits.map(function(single){
                        single._source.raw_companyProfile = single._source.companyProfile;
                        single._source.raw_email = single._source.email;
                        return single._source;
                    });
                    var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(result, params.orderBy()) : result;
                    $scope.$parent.total = response.total;
                    params.total(response.total);
                    $defer.resolve(orderedData);
                }, function (error){
                    console.log(error);
                }
            );


        }
    });
```

When I try to update `$scope.tableParams.data` and call reload nothing is update!

Please help me!

Comment: To transform an "external" promise into an angular promise, the appropriate function is $q.when(): https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when

Answer (score 0):

To transform an "external" promise into an angular promise, the appropriate function is `$q.when()`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when.

But reject is not async, and it doesn't return a promise: see http://underscorejs.org/#reject.

The problem, I think, is that you assume it removes elements from `$scope.tableParams.data`. It doesn't. It returns a new array that doesn't contain the rejected elements.